# Red5 1.0.7M10: Could not find or load main class Files

Tags: java, installation, red5

I was going to take a look at the latest 1.0.7 on a Windows 2012 server and downloaded the latest .zip.  I extracted the .zip into my normal Red5 directory (d:\program files (x86)\Red5) and tried to run red5.bat and got the error, "Could not find or load main class Files". However, RED5_HOME and JAVA_HOME have not changed.  What did I miss?

Output of the red5.bat file:

```
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>if NOT DEFINED RED5_MAINCLASS set RED5_MAINCLASS=org
    .red5.server.Bootstrap

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>if NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME goto err

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>REM JAVA options

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>REM You can set JVM additional options here if you w
    ant

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>if NOT DEFINED JVM_OPTS set JVM_OPTS=-Xverify:none -
    XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:InitialCodeCach
    eSize=8m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=32m -Dorg.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=t
    rue

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>REM Set up logging options

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>set LOGGING_OPTS=-Dlogback.ContextSelector=org.red5.
    logging.LoggingContextSelector -Dcatalina.useNaming=true

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>REM Set up security options

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>REM set SECURITY_OPTS=-Djava.security.debug=failure
    -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy="D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5/conf
    /red5.policy"

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>set SECURITY_OPTS=-Djava.security.debug=failure

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>REM Set up tomcat options

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>set TOMCAT_OPTS=-Dcatalina.home=D:\Program Files (x8
    6)\Red5

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>REM Setup python/jython path

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>set JYTHON_OPTS=-Dpython.home=lib

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>REM Combined java options

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>set JAVA_OPTS=-Dlogback.ContextSelector=org.red5.log
    ging.LoggingContextSelector -Dcatalina.useNaming=true -Djava.security.debug=fail
    ure  -Xverify:none -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseParNewGC
     -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=8m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=32m -Dorg.terracotta.quar
    tz.skipUpdateCheck=true -Dcatalina.home=D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5 -Dpython.hom
    e=lib

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>set RED5_CLASSPATH=D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5\red5-
    service.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5\conf;

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>if NOT DEFINED RED5_OPTS set RED5_OPTS=

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>goto launchRed5

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>echo Starting Red5
    Starting Red5

    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5>"D:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin\java" -Dlogback.Cont
    extSelector=org.red5.logging.LoggingContextSelector -Dcatalina.useNaming=true -D
    java.security.debug=failure  -Xverify:none -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseBiased
    Locking -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=8m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=3
    2m -Dorg.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true -Dcatalina.home=D:\Program Files
     (x86)\Red5 -Dpython.home=lib -cp "D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5\red5-service.jar;
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Red5\conf;" org.red5.server.Bootstrap
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young collector with
     the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future r
    elease
    Error: Could not find or load main class Files
```

I was finally able to get Red5 started by changing the red5.bat file and messing with the quotes around some of the parameters.  It's a Windows server so red5 is in c:\program files (x86)\red5.  Here is the modified red5.bat file and subsequent error:

```
if NOT DEFINED RED5_HOME set RED5_HOME=%~dp0

if NOT DEFINED RED5_MAINCLASS set RED5_MAINCLASS=org.red5.server.Bootstrap

if NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME goto err

if NOT DEFINED JVM_OPTS set JVM_OPTS=-Xverify:none -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=8m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=32m -Dorg.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true

set LOGGING_OPTS=-Dlogback.ContextSelector=org.red5.logging.LoggingContextSelector -Dcatalina.useNaming=true

set SECURITY_OPTS=-Djava.security.debug=failure

set TOMCAT_OPTS=-Dcatalina.home="%RED5_HOME%"
```

changed above line to include quotes

```
set JYTHON_OPTS=-Dpython.home=lib

set JAVA_OPTS=%LOGGING_OPTS% %SECURITY_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %JVM_OPTS% %TOMCAT_OPTS% %JYTHON_OPTS%

set RED5_CLASSPATH=%RED5_HOME%\red5-service.jar";"%RED5_HOME%\conf;%CLASSPATH%
```

Added quotes to end of first param and beginning of second.  Quotes are automatically added to front and end of parameter.

```
if NOT DEFINED RED5_OPTS set RED5_OPTS= 

goto launchRed5

:launchRed5
echo Starting Red5
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JAVA_OPTS% -cp "%RED5_CLASSPATH%" %RED5_MAINCLASS% %RED5_OPTS%
```

However, after I was able to get Red5 running, I added my app, eTutor, and tried to record a stream.  I got this error.

```
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-1] maple.classroom.MapleClassroom - W3C x-category:session x-event:connect c-ip:76.242.102.xxx c-client-id:0
[INFO] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-31] maple.classroom.MapleClassroom - W3C x-category:stream x-event:play c-ip:76.242.102.xxx x-sname:4fb77abf-56aa-45cd-8907-11aa2a333cb6
[INFO] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-32] maple.classroom.MapleClassroom - W3C x-category:stream x-event:play c-ip:76.242.102.xxx x-sname:4fb77abf-56aa-45cd-8907-11aa2a333cb6 x-name:CADEaudio/2820/MOB_49_0_2
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-1] org.red5.server.stream.StreamService - closeStream  stream id: 1 connection: WAOIKZMBN2YZO
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-1] org.red5.server.stream.StreamService - Stream not found - streamId: 1 connection: WAOIKZMBN2YZO
[INFO] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-17] maple.classroom.MapleClassroom - W3C x-category:stream x-event:stop c-ip:76.242.102.xxx cs-bytes:3953 sc-bytes:4031 x-sname:4fb77abf-56aa-45cd-8907-11aa2a333cb6
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-4] org.red5.server.scope.BasicScope - ClientBroadcastStream already exists: org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream@60f07d5c new: org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream@60f07d5c
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-4] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Stream start: CADEaudio/2820/MOB_49_0_2
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-4] maple.classroom.MapleClassroom - W3C x-category:stream x-event:record-start c-ip:76.242.102.xxx x-sname:22665dc5-26ea-470a-98b5-0cf9b5894d5c x-file-name:MOB_49_0_2.flv
[WARN] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-24] org.red5.server.stream.RecordingListener - Exception while pushing to consumer
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException: null
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.mina.core.buffer.AbstractIoBuffer.get(AbstractIoBuffer.java:625)
        at org.apache.mina.core.buffer.AbstractIoBuffer.get(AbstractIoBuffer.java:1337)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.ImmutableTag.build(ImmutableTag.java:183)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$QueuedData.<init>(FileConsumer.java:795)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.pushMessage(FileConsumer.java:256)
        at org.red5.server.stream.RecordingListener.processQueue(RecordingListener.java:319)
        at org.red5.server.stream.RecordingListener.access$300(RecordingListener.java:57)
        at org.red5.server.stream.RecordingListener$EventQueueJob.execute(RecordingListener.java:383)
        at org.red5.server.scheduling.QuartzSchedulingServiceJob.executeInternal(QuartzSchedulingServiceJob.java:89)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

Comment: Files, is a Jdk 8 class; nothing to do with Red5. The first step may be to install Java 8 on your machine.

Comment: Java 8 has been on this server since it was built and that's what 1.0.6 has been using.  I added the output of the red5.bat file above.  JDK is currently 1.8.77

Comment: I'm talking about this: Error: Could not find or load main class Files from your text; Red5 doesn't use that class, its in your app.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm struggling to understand.  I've just unpacked the 1.0.7 package as is and haven't put my app in webapps yet.  Just trying to run red5.bat first.  Webapps contains chat, installer, live, root, and vod.  I know you're telling me something I should know, but I'm not getting it yet.

Comment: I have edited the post and shown where I added quotes to the red5.bat file to get Red5 started.  I tried to record a quick test stream but it got the error posted above.  I'm not sure if this is something new or if my changes messed up its operation.

Comment: Looks like your record start happened after your stream was already gone; so it couldn't read the bytes; buffer underflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the original problem is fixed.  The issue was in the red5.bat file and the handling of quotes around file paths. I had to put quotes around:

```
set TOMCAT_OPTS=-Dcatalina.home="%RED5_HOME%"
```

The RED5_CLASSPATH added its own quotes to the classpath value on the start and end but didn't add them to the individual parameters.  So, I also had to put "inside" the following statement so each parameter was quoted:

```
set RED5_CLASSPATH=%RED5_HOME%\red5-service.jar";"%RED5_HOME%\conf;%CLASSPATH%
```

I have no idea yet what this is going to do when I try to run it as a service, but I'm hoping when 1.0.7 final is released, all will be good.  There is the one error but that's another issue and post.

Comment: The production version of 1.0.7 has the same problem with the red5.bat file and the inconsistent use of quotes.

Comment: Thank you for this. I can't imagine how I would have solved this problem without your answer.

Comment: Velocedge, were you able to run this as a Windows Service? I'm getting the FindClass error although I'm able to run it normally after the quotes change.