# Red5 1.0.8M13 runs using .bat file but Windows service gives error

Tags: java, windows-services, red5

I'm trying to install Red5 1.0.8 M13 as a service on Windows 2008 server.  Red5 and my webapp run fine when starting with red5.bat but it immediately stops and fails when running as a service with:

```
"Windows could not start the Red5 media server on local computer. For more information view the system event log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service specific error code 4."
```

System Event Log contains:

```
"The Red5 Media Server service terminated with service-specific error The system cannot open the file."
```

The red5-error.log contains:

```
2016-10-31 09:27:07 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseStringCache; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young collector with the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Exception in thread "main"
```

JAVA_HOME=c:\program files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

Service path is: c:\program files (x86)\Red5\amd64\prunsrv.exe //RS//Red5

What have I missed?

Comment: In the event log it talks about "The system cannot open the file"... anyone have any idea what file it might be talking about?

Comment: Red5 as a windows service uses Apache Commons Daemon and we have seen issues running it on various windows flavors; we are unsure at this time as to what the actual issue is.

Comment: I just uninstalled all versions of Java and reinstalled the 32 bit jdk.  In the log I get: [2016-11-01 09:08:16] [error] [  636] Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2016-11-01 09:08:16] [error] [  636] The system cannot find the path specified.  I have JAVA_HOME and path variables using c:\progra~2\Java\jdk1.8 but the service obviously doesn't see it that way.

Comment: Ok, so I uninstalled the 32bit Java and installed the 64 bit version in c:\program files\java\jdk1.8 and changed the environment variables.  Now the log shows: [2016-11-01 09:37:05] [info]  [ 2968] Starting service...
[2016-11-01 09:37:05] [error] [ 3104] FindClass Main failed
[2016-11-01 09:37:05] [error] [ 2968] Failed to start Java
[2016-11-01 09:37:05] [error] [ 2968] ServiceStart returned 4

Comment: I did have to change the red5.bat file to deal with the quotes properly as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456351/red5-1-0-7m10-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-files.  I don't know if that has any relationship to this problem.

Comment: So you do, or don't have it working now? Also I recommend Java 8 100% from now on

Comment: I do not have it working.  I was hoping that it would give you a clue to the problem when it said "Program Files/Java" in the error log when JAVA_HOME contained "Program Files (x86)/Java".  Also, should I be using 32 bit or 64 bit Java on a 64 bit server?

Comment: On the red5.bat reference, that was just to let you know that the bat file does not work from the standard install on Windows.  You have to modify it if the path contains spaces (like "Program Files").

Comment: 64 bit java on a 64 bit system is suggested. The path worked well the last time I tested the installer on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you using a path of "Program Files"?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, but I can guesss that you need to set the `RED_HOME` variable. Please look at your bat file to understand which variables you might want to set.

Comment: Sorry, should have said RED5_HOME is set to c:\Program Files (x86)\Red5 which is where the files are.  Don't think it would have run as a .bat without it.   As far as variables being set, I thought everything was done in the config.  Have around a dozen Red5 servers and can't quite see why they are different... and work as services.   None are running 1.0.8 of course.

Comment: I see, then I'm out of ideas, sorry about that (

Answer (score 0):

I looked at some of my other servers to see where there was a difference.  I used "prunmgr //ms //red5" to look at the configuration.  On the startup tab, Class was empty and my other servers had "org.red5.server.Bootstrap".  So, I put that in the 1.0.8 server's config using prunmgr and it worked!  Not sure what that all means, but working is good!

Answer (score 0):

this problem occur when the RED5 path is too long

just put it in C:\red5 it will work